# Different distances of axis labels from the plot borders

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to prepare plot for a publication, but, interestingly, x-axis ticks are more closer to the plot border, than y-axis ticks. How can I set the distances equal to each other?

```
plot(x, y, cex.axis = 3,
             xlim = c(0, 0.9*max(c(x, y))), ylim = c(0, 0.9*max(c(x, y))),
             xlab = "",
             ylab = "",
             mgp = c(3, 2.4, 0))
```

[image: Here's what I get]

Comment: So that's the default behaviour? I don't need to rotate ticks, thanks